# Test jar dependency in Play?

Tags: scala, maven, playframework

I have a maven module which has some common code for integration tests in test sources directory. I build a test-jar containing these classes.

in Maven I would use following (as said in http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.myco.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <type>test-jar</type> <!-- this is the important part-->
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

in order to use this in another module.

How do I define such dependency on test-jar in Play (or SBT)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the "tests" classifier, as explained in this [doc](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management#classifiers):

```
"com.myco.app" % "foo" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT" % "test" classifier "tests"
```